# It is possible to create "permanent" recordings in vim?

Tags: vim

I really like the recording feature of vim, however sometimes I need "permanent" recording. I don't want to define the very same recording every time. Instead, I am looking for a solution like "saving a recording(!) to `.vimrc` file so that it is loaded every time I open vim". something like that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recordings are saved in registers and registers are, usually, saved in your `~/.viminfo` file between sessions, so that's at least one level of permanency out of the box.

A more permanent solution would be to store your macro manually in your `vimrc`:

```
let @a = "lqhjdfgflqsdhjqsfgd"
```

Typically, the process would look like this:

```
:e $MYVIMRC    " edit your vimrc
Go             " go to last line and open a new line below
let @a = "     " start typing
<C-r>a         " insert the content of the desired register
"              " insert closing quote
<Esc>          " leave insert mode
```

But recorded macros are full of weird artifacts (like `<80>j`, etc.) that you will need to remove yourself.

`:help setreg()` is another way to do the same thing.

That said, both solutions suffer from a common flaw: registers `@a-z` are all writeable. This means that, even if it is possible to set a register at startup, there is nothing preventing it from being overwritten later during the session.

Another possibility is to save the macro as a mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> lqhjdfgflqsdhjqsfgd
```

which, depending on what `<key>` you choose, might be slightly less prone to overriding.

A command and/or a function are also potentially safer.

The bottom line is that everything "global" can be overridden in one way or another in vimscript so you *will* have to make compromises, here.

---

See [this gist of mine](https://gist.github.com/romainl/9721c7dd13c30714f568063e03c106dd).

Comment: that' was a nice and detailed explanation. thanks!